# Div vs SVG for Javascript Treemap

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, treemap

I need a treemap like the one from plotly:
https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/
for a react application,
which supports a zoom functionality, so that multiple layers can be explored, without the need to show all layers at once.
I can't use plotly, because it seems to violate the CSP and I could not find any other library, with an example that worked for me.

I know think about writing a custom treemap component. Every treemap I tried was built as SVG. However, I have no experience with SVG's and would prefer to build the treemap with div elements. Since I could not find any solution that uses div elements, I wonder if there is any pitfall, which I don't know about.

I know that too many DOM elements might be a problem. But I don't need to show more than 2 layers at once, which are never more than 200 elements.

Comment: It's possible, even with lots of divs. But you probably underestimate how much work it is to create a tree with full functionality. Maybe you can use d3.js? https://d3js.org

Comment: Or VEGA treemap: https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/treemap/

Answer (score 2):

This example is the beginning of something that could take form as a tree. It is made with divs based on the object `data`.

I began to style it, but it takes some experimentation and structuring...

```js
const data = {
  '1': {
    '1.1': {
      '1.1.1': {}
    },
    '1.2': {}
  },
  '2': {
    '2.1': {},
    '2.2': {
      '2.2.1': {},
      '2.2.2': {}
    }
  }
};

const tree = document.getElementById('tree');

const insertchildren = (parent, obj, level) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    let child = document.createElement('div');
    child.setAttribute('class', `node v${Object.keys(obj[key]).length} l${level}`);
    let title = document.createElement('div');
    title.setAttribute('class', 'title');
    title.textContent = key;
    child.appendChild(title);
    parent.appendChild(child);
    insertchildren(child, obj[key], level + 1);
  });
};

insertchildren(tree, data, 1);
```

```css
div#tree {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.l1 {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.l2 {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.l3 {
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.node {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid thin black;
  margin: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
}

.v0 {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tree" class="v2"></div>
```